# cyclic randomization for a group of variables in SystemVerilog

Tags: constraints, verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to randomize 3 different variables in system verilog but in a cyclic fashion. What I mean is, I have the following 3 variables

```
rand int a;
rand int b;
rand int c;

constraint c_a{
  a inside {1,2};     
}
constraint c_b{
  b inside {1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
constraint c_c{
  c inside {1,2,3}
}
```

With the above constraints, there are a total of 36 combinations of all the 3 variables (2x6x3).

But if we run a loop of 36, like so :

```
repeat(36) begin
  this.randomize(a,b,c);
  $display("%d   %d   %d", a,b,c);
end
```

we wont hit all the possible combinations as some combinations might be repeated. Hence I'm looking to find a way to hit all those combinations by running the loop exactly 36 times.

I wrote a brute force way to do this by declaring another rand variable to represent each combination and using randc on it like so :

```
int a;
int b;
int c;
randc int k;

constraint c_k{
  k inside {[1:36]};
}

repeat(36) begin
  this.randomize(k);
  // randomizing variable 'a' to one of the 2 values.
  if(k<9)
    a = 1;
  else
    a = 2;
  // randomizing variable 'b' to one of the 6 values.
  case(k)
    1,2,3,19,20,21 : b = 1;
    4,5,6,22,23,24 : b = 2;
    7,8,9,25,26,27 : b = 3;
    //
    //   finishing the sequence
    // 
  endcase  

  case(k)
     // similar case statement for the final variable
  endcase

  $display("%d, %d, %d", a,b,c);
end
```

The above way works fine, but to me it seemed kind of a hectic way (which also cannot be applied for large combinations) and hence wondering if there is a more elegant method to achieve this.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is concatenate your variables into a packed struct and make that a **randc** variable.

```
module top;
class A;
    typedef struct packed {
    bit [1:0]   a;
    bit [2:0]   b;
    bit [1:0]   c;
    } abc_t;
randc abc_t k;
constraint c_a{
  k.a inside {1,2};     
}
constraint c_b{
  k.b inside {1,2,3,4,5,6};
}
constraint c_c{
  k.c inside {1,2,3};
}
endclass
   A h = new;
   initial 
     repeat(40) begin
       h.randomize();
       $display("%0p",h.k);
     end
endmodule
```

Be aware that the total number of bits allowed for a `randc` variable may be limited by the simulator

Comment: Thanks Dave. While trying this out, I found that the simulator I use allows upto 32 bits or just 1 'int' type. This seems to be small. I see why you've changed the data types from 'int' (in my example) to 'bit'.

Comment: Think of what you needed to deal with _6-bits_ of cyclic randomness. You essentially had to map out all the possible solutions and randomly pick one of them. A constraint solver has to do something similar and the problem grows exponentially as the number of bits increases.

Any other approach to this problem needs to know the exact number of possible solutions, and that becomes very difficult as the constraints get more complex.